# Two-finger scrolling not working since ubuntu 17.10+

Tags: 18.04, touchpad, 17.10, scrolling

I recently upgraded to *ubuntu 17.10* and since then I cannot do *two finger scrolling*, only *edge scrolling*. Any suggestions how to make the *two finger scrolling* work again? I use a *Lenovo ThinkPad 450s*

---

Output of `xinput list-props $(xinput list | perl -ne '/touchpad.*\bid=(\d*)/i && print $1')` as requested by @Hi-Angel

```
Device 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad':
Device Enabled (141):   1
Coordinate Transformation Matrix (143): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
libinput Tapping Enabled (276): 1
libinput Tapping Enabled Default (277): 0
libinput Tapping Drag Enabled (278):    1
libinput Tapping Drag Enabled Default (279):    1
libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled (280):   0
libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled Default (281):   0
libinput Tapping Button Mapping Enabled (282):  1, 0
libinput Tapping Button Mapping Default (283):  1, 0
libinput Accel Speed (284): 0.600000
libinput Accel Speed Default (285): 0.000000
libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (286):   1
libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (287):   0
libinput Send Events Modes Available (261): 1, 1
libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (262):    0, 0
libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (263):    0, 0
libinput Left Handed Enabled (288): 0
libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (289): 0
libinput Scroll Methods Available (290):    1, 1, 0
libinput Scroll Method Enabled (291):   0, 1, 0
libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (292):   1, 0, 0
libinput Click Methods Available (293): 1, 1
libinput Click Method Enabled (294):    1, 0
libinput Click Method Enabled Default (295):    1, 0
libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (296):    0
libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (297):    0
libinput Disable While Typing Enabled (298):    1
libinput Disable While Typing Enabled Default (299):    1
Device Node (264):  "/dev/input/event5"
Device Product ID (265):    2, 7
libinput Drag Lock Buttons (300):   <no items>
libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (301):   1
```

Answer (score 91):

The answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/971735/101985) by @hpotter40 worked for me:

```
$ sudo modprobe -r psmouse
$ sudo modprobe psmouse
```

This was taken from comment #16 of this bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1722478/comments/16

---

**Update for a more persistent solution:**

Based on comment #44 and #45 of the same bug report above, this should also work. Open the file **`/etc/default/grub`** and edit the value of the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` variable. By default this has the value of `"quiet splash"`. The value **`"psmouse.synaptics_intertouch=0"`** could be added to it so that it becomes like:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash psmouse.synaptics_intertouch=0"
```

Then update GRUB by executing:

```
$ sudo update-grub
```

Reboot your system and this setting should survive even after suspends. As a note, all these answers are simply workarounds until the kernel error could be identified and patched.

Comment: This works for me, but every time my computer goes to sleep I have to rerun this again and again.

Comment: Same here... it works but have to rerun after sleep (I'm actually still on 16.04 though).

Comment: doesn't work for me, two fingers still doesn't scrolling, it seems like restarting mouse functionality

Comment: I had the same problem in 18.04, this answer solved my problem, thank you.

Comment: Anyone got a lasting fix for this? Is there any `.*rc` file or something that runs after waking from sleep that we could put these commands in?

Comment: Persistent fix: add `psmouse.synaptics_intertouch=0` to your grub config. See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1722478/comments/44

Answer (score 8):

You can enable *two finger scroll* by clicking `System Settings > Mouse & Touchpad`. You will see a window like this
[image]

You can (un)check the check box according to your preference.

Comment: This is a new problem affecting the latest version of Ubuntu (17.10) and specifically ThinkPads. There's a bug report here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1722478