# Internal error on start up. Executable path: usr/bin/gnome-shell

Tags: command-line, grub2, gnome, touchpad

Specs: Running Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS 64-bit on a Lenovo Thinkpad X240.

Yesterday I tried to fix a recurring issue regarding my touchpad. Two-finger scrolling wasn't working anymore, so I used to advice given in [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/970988/two-finger-scrolling-not-working-since-ubuntu-17-10). I followed the exact instructions listed under the "Update for a more persistent solution" header in the top reply, including using a `$ sudo update-grub` command. In addition, I "save-as'd" the /etc/default/grub file after having edited the value, and replaced the existing file.

I've obviously made a mistake, because now I'm experiencing internal errors on start up. I'm faced with a blank screen until either my home screen appears (after around 10-15s), or until the internal error notification appears.

I've found my "_usr_bin_gnome-shell.1000.crash" file, and can supply it if necessary/helpful.

Thanks!